# Ubuntu strange encoding issues using sublime text 2

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, encoding, sublimetext2

I'm running ubuntu 13.04 64bit, using sublime text 2 writing PHP. I sometimes seem to get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Â ' (T_STRING) in
/home/afflicto/public_html/html/HTML.php on line 10
```

It is solved by removing the entire line and re-writing it.
The character is not visible in the source code.

What's going on? this only happens on ubuntu, never happened on windows.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you doing when this happens? Can you paste in the offending line(s) of code before you fix it? Where is the error coming from - running the PHP file or in Sublime itself? What relevant plugins do you have installed?

Comment: Hi MattDmo: It is PHP who throws the error. I will copy and paste the code next time it happens. I haven't tried disabling plugins but the ones I have are: emmet, laravel blade highlighter and a few others.

Comment: Other people are having this issue, but I don't know why it's happening: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9607

Answer (score 0):

What probably is happening is that you are holding alt while pressing space (ALT+space), entering a non-breaking space instead of a regular space. I'm not 100% sure about Ubuntu, but it's a common problem in OSX.

To fix it in Sublime Text, add the following to Preferences/Key Bindings - User:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+space"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": " " } },
```

Note that if you have additional lines in the file you need to keep the trailing `,` - otherwise remove it.

Read more below:

https://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces